# How to Create MULTIPLE bundles in iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, bundles

Hi I have a situation where my application can be used for different purposes depending on certain inputs.

Ex: I have a **Theme.js** which will have contents for **Type A** and another **Theme.js** will have contents for **Type B**. Here i will need to create a two bundles so that my application automatically will point to the bundle which will be used and use resources from that particular bundle.

I am not getting where to start with like How do i create a bundle. Is new file >resources> settings.bundle ?

ANY HELP WOULD REALLY BE APPRECIATED :)

Comment: you need this for a single target or targets will be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1)** Make new folder on Mac
**Step 2)** Add files to folder
**Step 3)** Add .bundle extension to that folder
**Step 4)** Add the file to XCode 
**Step 5)** ...?
**Step 6)** PROFIT!

Comment: Hey How to i Add files to that . .How is the files accessed from that bundle ? I am not able to look at the files inside that please help

Comment: I guess I should revise my answer...  As for the second part, right click on the bundle file and click show package contents.