# Failing to store xib files to an own bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, nsbundle

In my project I've created an own Settings Bundle (called UIBundle), and dragged to it some of xib files. Then I'm trying to load them from bundle, for example this table view cell xib:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[self xibsBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (NSBundle *) xibsBundle
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UIBundle" ofType:@"bundle"];
    return [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
}
```

But every time I run my app, it crashes when trying to load a cell with the following message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../App.app/UIBundle.bundle> (not yet loaded)' with name 'MyCell''
```

Spent one day finding a solution without success. Any help would be appreciated.

**P.S. Bundle is loaded successfully and any other resource besides xib files is accessible.**

Comment: Maybe this question could help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904615/how-to-create-multiple-bundles-in-iphone-application Is your bundle retrieved and other content accesible?

Comment: @Lepidopteron Hi. Any other resource besides xib files is accessible.

Comment: Have you tried this approach, to add resources this way to your bundle as a library? http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix my issue was to follow the following steps:

1. Create a XCode project with type: MacOS platform.
2. From the section **Framework & Library** choose **Bundle**.
3. Then add all the xib files to the project.
4. Change Base SDK from Build Settings to `Latest iOS`.
5. Build the project.
6. Then expand Products folder and open the bundle file. 
   There must be all the nib files.

I copied them to my own bundle and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using class method **bundleWithIdentifier:** of NSBundle class.

```
- (NSBundle *) xibsBundle {

    return [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"UIBundle"];    
}
```

**OR**

If you know path to the bundle, then try using the following:

```
myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"Path\to\UIBundle"];
```

For more information, refer this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html

Comment: This method returns nil in my case.

Comment: Do you know path to the bundle?
If yes, then try using the following:

myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"Path\to\UIBundle"];

Comment: The path to the bundle is know, it is also loaded successfully, as the comments to his question indicate. Maybe the question could be updated.